# Can I use jQuery's load() function to load data into a tag's attribute?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can I do something like this:

```
$('#myTag').attr('value').load('my_php_file.php');
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ based on this I don't see why not!

Comment: You can, but not in the way you are doing it. Even so, it would make more sense to do it using `$.get` or `$.ajax` since it wouldn't require creating a dummy dom element to temporarily contain the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because `.attr('value')` returns a string (representing the value of the `value` attribute on the DOM element) and it is pretty meaningless to call the `.load()` method on a string. You usually call this method on a DOM element. To illustrate your problem, here's what your code is equivalent to:

```
var value = 'some value';
value.load('my_php_file.php');
```

Nonesense.

Did you mean:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'my_php_file.php', 
    success: function(result) { 
        $('#myTag').val(result); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: What's I'm trying to do is ajax in a value into a tags value attribute.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. You mean like the value attribute of this DOM element is pointing to the id of some other DOM element that you want to feed with the results of an AJAX call?

Comment: I have an input tag (text field), and I want to change the value inside the text field via ajax.

Comment: You mean like `$.ajax({ url: 'my_php_file.php', success: function(result) { $('#myTag').val(result); } });`?

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. I have to leave right now, but I'll try that when I get back. Thanks for the suggestion!